# How to save a Java FloatBuffer (or any Buffer) to a file

Tags: java, file, buffer

I have a FloatBuffer of known size and just want to dump the data to a file (in binary) for inspection outside my app. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE FOR BINARY OUTPUT:

```
// There are dependencies on how you create your floatbuffer for this to work
// I suggest starting with a byte buffer and using asFloatBuffer() when
// you need it as floats.
// ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(somesize);
// FloatBuffer fb = b.asFloatBuffer();
// There will also be endiance issues when you write binary since
// java is big-endian. You can adjust this with Buffer.order(...)
// b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
// If you're using a hex-editor you'll probably want little endian output
// since most consumer machines (unless you've got a sparc / old mac) are little


FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("some_binary_output_file_name");
FileChannel channel = fos.getChannel();

channel.write(byteBufferBackingYourFloatBuffer);

fos.close();
```

TEXT OUTPUT:
Since you want this to be viewable I assume you want a text file. You'll want to use a PrintStream.

```
// Try-catch omitted for simplicity

PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("some_output_file.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < yourFloatBuffer.capacity(); i++)
{
   // put each float on one line
   // use printf to get fancy (decimal places, etc)
   ps.println(yourFloagBuffer.get(i));
}

ps.close();
```

Didn't have time to post a full raw/binary (non-text) version of this. If you want to do that use a [FileOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), get the [FileChannel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), and directly write the [FloatBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html) (since it's a [ByteBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html))

Comment: Thanks, although actually I did want to write it all out in binary. Sorry to not be specific about that, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

Asusming you want the data as binary:

Start with a `ByteBuffer`. Call `asFloatBuffer` to get your `FloatBuffer`. When you've finished doing your stuff, save the `ByteBuffer` out to a `WritableByteChannel`.

If you already have `FloatBuffer` it can be copied into the buffer from step 2 with a `put`.

A low performance but easier way would be to use `Float.floatToIntBit`.

(Watch for endianess, obviously.)

Answer (score -1):

This iterates through the array backed by your buffer and outputs each float.  Just replace the text file and floatBuffer with your own parameters.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream("target.txt");
for(float f : floatBuffer.array()){
  out.println(f);
}
out.close();
```